# Log4j loss connection database after some hours

Tags: java, log4j

i have this configuration for log4j for my web services:

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.logger.com.package = INFO, DB

# Define the DB appender
log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender

# Set JDBC URL
log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/MYDB

# Set Database Driver
log4j.appender.DB.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# Set database user name and password
log4j.appender.DB.user=agent
log4j.appender.DB.password=secret
# Set the SQL statement to be executed.
log4j.appender.DB.sql=INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES(TIMESTAMP(now()),'%C','%p','%m')

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.DB.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Works, but after some hours (no operations) loss connection and not save anything into DB.

There is some configuration that i missed?

Is possible set something like:

```
log4j.appender.DB.testOnBorrow = true
log4j.appender.DB.validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
```

Comment: Double check to see if you have a close on the appender anywhere.  This has given me troubles on similar loggers (Log4Net).  It could be causing an object is disposed error.

Comment: the only configuration that i have is in the question. You think in the code i call close connection?

Comment: The close would be a part of your code and the implementation of log4j, if you do not have it then you are properly setting this up, the issue is elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try setting the autoreconnect parameter in the connection string?

```
log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/MYDB?autoReconnect=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the database server isn't timing out your session for the logger connection and closing it from the server side, if you're going "some hours" with no activity. On MySQL, this is [wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) and it defaults to 8 hours if I'm reading that right. This is a server-side configuration.